three way light switch change fron old to new
Converting an old Australian 3-way light switch

to this switch:

Would I be right to wire it like this?


You need to make sure the wire with neutral colour is being used as neutral.  We use white for neutral in NA, but often white is also used as hot or traveller in older switches.  It is suppose to be marked as not neutral(black tape), but people are lazy.  Connecting a not neutral to real neutral, can make life interesting.  Look up switch loops.

@crip659 This is in Australia. North America standards are irrelevant.

Terminology clarification: when you write "3-way light switch", are you referring to a single switch plate with 3 individual switches, each controlling 3 individual (sets of) lights? Or are you using North-American terminology where "3-way switch" refers to a situation where you have 2 (or more) switches in different locations all controlling the same lights?

Thanks, To clarify: This is a light switch to three different lights. This is the switch https://detaelectrical.com.au/product/deta-touch-activated-triple-gang-light-switch/ https://www.bunnings.com.au/deta-touch-activated-triple-gang-light-switch_p0161016


A lot use none standard colours as the switch Hot/live returns, I would assume the main hot/live goes into A, the N/Neutral terminal goes into N, then the switched Hot/Live go into A 1-3, I can not see how the new switch can do 2 way switching. The loops as not required on the new switch.
EDIT: I DONT have the knowledge of the new switch, but it maybe possible to program A3 and A4 to work as a two way light switch system, if so you just have to place the far right red into A3 and the white into A4, let us know.

Thanks @Johnliverpool. i updated mu diagram in the OP, because I can't embed an image in a comment. Would you mind commenting on whether that's the right solution
